# C++ copy constructor and assignment operator question

Tags: c++

I have the following code and am trying to understand the copy constructor and assignment operator.  I can follow along all the way to where this code prints out `p0`.  I'm confused per comments in code, why the default constructor and copy constructor are not called.  Appreciate any guidance on why this is happening?  Thanks

```
#include <iostream>

class X {
public:
  X();
  X(const X &s);
  X &operator=(const X &s);
};

X::X()
{
  std::cout << "X()" << '\n';
}

X::X(const X &s)
{
  std::cout << "X(cc)" << '\n';
}

X& X::operator=(const X &s)
{
  std::cout << "X(ao)" << '\n';
  return *this;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  /* call empty () cons */
  X s1, s2;

  /* both same call ao */
  s2 = s1;
  s2.operator=(s1);

  /* call cc */
  X s3(s1);
  std::cout << "p0" << '\n';
  X s4 = X();
  /* why is default constructor and copy constructor not called? */
  std::cout << "p1" << '\n';
  X s5(X());
  /* why is default constructor not called? */
  std::cout << "p2" << '\n';
  X s6();

  return 0;
}

g++ test50.cc && ./a.out
X()
X()
X(ao)
X(ao)
X(cc)
p0
X()
p1
p2
```

UPDATE: per comments this does look like:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: `X s5(X());` -- Most vexing parse?

Comment: `X s4 = X();` possibly copy elision (pre C++17).

Comment: `X s6();` is function declaration ("vexing parse")

Comment: My compiler `-Wvexing-parse` warns about the vexing parse issue.

Comment: That's the first I've seen a double "vexing parse" in the same code when it wasn't done on purpose :)